# How to represent time-frequency dependence of an azimuth angle without colors?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, matlab-figure

I have a frequency-time-azimuth angle plot. The azimuth angle is color-coded. Is there any way to represent these data without colors? Or how to do it with only black and white color code?

[image: an example of frequency-time-azimuth angle plot, that must be represent with no colors]

Answer (score 0):

You can always use BW gradient:

[image]

Or surface plot to improve visibility:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you would just like to check the data out with a different mapping, try

```
doc colormap
colormap('gray')
```